# In a game programming project, how do I handle multiple items with multiple instances?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

Assuming that I have a 2 player game that has multiple weapons in it. At the start of the game, the players can choose their own weapons and equip it to their characters. So if Right now, I have the following code to implement the said scenario:

```
public class Weapon {
    private String name;
    private int attackPoints;
    private int effectivity = 100;

    public Weapon(String name, int attackPoints) {
        this.name = name;
        this.attackPoints = attackPoints;
    }
    // ...
}

public class Character {
    private String name;
    private Weapon weapon;

    public Character(String name, Weapon weapon) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }
    // ...
}

public class Game {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void createCharacter() {
        String namePlayer = "Knight";
        String nameOpponent = "Thief";

        //Weapon Menu
        System.out.println("Select weapon");
        System.out.println("1. Dagger - Attack: 10");
        System.out.println("2. Sword - Attack 20");

        Character player;
        Character opponent;
        int choice = scanner.nextInt();

        //Weapon assignment
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            player = new Character(name, new Weapon("Dagger", 10));
            break;
        case 2:
            player = new Character(name, new Weapon("Sword", 20));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

### Rephrased the question

My concern is, what if I have to add an additional weapon, say "Ax with 15 damage" for example, then I'd have to modify the weapon menu, and at the same time add an additional case in my switch statement. Is it possible that I'd only have to modify some kind of a list and it'll take care of the list of weapons available for the player to choose and at the same time make the instances of the weapons different for the player and the opponent character?

### Old question

My concern is, every time I have a new weapon, I have to modify the weapons menu and at the same time modify the weapon assignment part. Is there a better way for implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need a `WeaponFactory`, which would know about all the `Weapon`s available. This factory also can create a new instance of particular Weapon based on users input. This way, I think, you will achieve all you need

- all the weapons are created in a single place,
- adding new one requires to change single class.

Here is an simplified example.

```
public static class WeaponFactory {
    public List<Weapon> availableWeapons() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Dagger(), new Rifle());
    }

    public Weapon create(int type) {
        return availableWeapons().get(type);
    }
}

public interface Weapon {
    public abstract double attack();
    public abstract String name();
}

public static abstract class WeaponAdapter implements Weapon {
    @Override public String toString() {  return name() + " - " + attack(); }
}

public static class Dagger extends WeaponAdapter {
    @Override public double attack() { return 10; }
    @Override public String name() { return "Dagger"; }
}

public static class Rifle extends WeaponAdapter {
    @Override public double attack() { return 80; }
    @Override public String name() { return "Rifle"; }
}
```

There is a bit of inefficiency as it's not really required to create new instances of `Weapon`s in order to show them in `Menu`, but I think it's good enough for the sake of this example.

To mitigate this, you could use a bit of reflection or use enums for that. What you basically need is a function, which would create a Weapon based on it's type, so it might be smth like

```
List<Class<? extends Weapon>> weapons = Arrays.asList(Dagger.class, Rifle.class);

public Weapon create(Class<Weapon> weaponType) {
    try {
        return weaponType.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Not possible");
    }
}
```

Again, all this is part of the `WeaponFactory`, which is a single place to all `Weapon`s related.

Answer (score 0):

You Character class can have a list of Weapons like this:

```
public class Character {
private String name;
private List<Weapon> weapons = new ArrayList<Weapon>();

 public Character(String name) { //keep this constructor. I know I have omitted weapons variable from this constructor.
    this.name = name;        
}
// down below you have getters and setters for name and weapons
}
```

Then when you initialize a new Character, do this:

```
Character player1;
...

switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        Weapon w = new Weapon("Dagger", 10));
        player = new Character(name);
        player.getWeapons().add(w);
        break;
```

Comment: Thanks, for your reply, I must have phrased my question vaguely. My concern is, what if I have to add an additional weapon, say "Ax with 15 damage" for example, then I'd have to modify the weapon menu, and at the same time add an additional case in my switch statement. Is it possible that I'd only have to modify some kind of a list and it'll take care of the list of weapons available for the player to choose and at the same time make the instance of player to the opponent character different?

Comment: I see.. So I really have to add an additional weapon in the menu part. Like so:
         //Weapon Menu
        System.out.println("Select weapon");
        System.out.println("1. Dagger - Attack: 10");
        System.out.println("2. Sword - Attack 20");
        System.out.println("3. Ax - Attack 15"); <<-- additional

Comment: @asker I still couldn't understand your question. Can you repeat the question? Thanks

Comment: given that at the start of the game, players would select their own weapon of choice. Assuming that in the middle of the game, some attributes of the weapon would change for each character, then we need the weapons to have different instances. In the current implementation, if I'm going to add an additional weapon in the menu, I'd have to modify the menu list and at the same time modify the switch statement for both player and opponent weapon assignment. So my question is, is there a better way for me to implement it? Thanks.

Comment: @asker okay asker I have edited my answer. I think I understand now what you are saying. If this is not what you are looking for, then I will need to see the FULL code and I will need to play around with it till I get it right. Then I can show you the answer and you can understand what to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can..

..create every weapon as object add it to an array (or List etc), so you have not to code

```
System.out.println("Select weapon");
System.out.println("1. Dagger - Attack: 10");
System.out.println("2. Sword - Attack 20");
```

you can go for

```
    Weapon[] weapons = new Weapon[2];
    weapons[0] = new Weapon ("Dagger",10);
    weapons[1] = new Weapon ("Sword",20);
    for (int i = 0; i < weapons.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(i+1+". "weapons[i].getName+" - "+weapons[i].getAttackPoints);
    }
    int choice = scanner.nextInt();
    player = new Character(namePlayer, weapons[choice-1]);
```

just to take care that

- the class Weapon has getters for Name and Attackpoints
- and that arrays start as shown here with index 0

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but if I do so, then the dagger instance found in the player character would also have the instance found in the opponent character. Is there a way make the instances of weapons different for both types of characters?

Comment: @asker yes you're right the instance then will be the same but the question is why do you need different instances, because a sword is a sword even if player or opponent has one, so a weapon class as itself exists without direct link to a character. If you need different instances you can use the  [clone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_(Java_method)) method of but this seems to me as even more a design topic - so coming back why do think you have to use different instances?

Comment: assuming that a weapon can be customized like it gets damaged as the players are using it. So in this case the instances needs to be different. I've also asked some of my colleagues, and they've also suggested that I implement a clone method. But is it the proper way to do it or is there a better way ?

Comment: i agree and so we go into some more details for the object oriented design - when i imagine how it should be done then there a two hearts beating
*1 one says make a good architecture 
*2 the other one make it pragmatical
for 1 i would say make it close to what's in the real world that means create a class that manages all the available weapons something like a WeaponShop, so you can as you say also sell used weapons

Comment: and you can go through all existing, and when you order a weapon you receive a unique one, not one from the catalog 
for 2 i would say do just the things you need so clone it
maybe the best is as always something in between. but that depends whats in your mind and the intention of the game :-)